# Adiabatic invariance of a particle with negative energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, adiabatic

> Given a particle with negative total energy in the potential $$V=-\frac{V_0}{\cosh^2({\alpha}x)}$$
> with $\alpha > 0$, I must show that under small and slow variations of $V_0$, the quantity $$\frac{V_0 + E}{\sqrt{V_0}}$$
> is adiabatic invariant.

Here's what I did: since the total energy is $E=\frac{1}{2}m\dot{x}^2 + V$, its total derivative is
$$\frac{dE}{dt}= \dot{x}(m\ddot{x}+2{\alpha}V_0 \mathrm{sech}^2({\alpha}x)\tanh({\alpha}x)) - \mathrm{sech}^2({\alpha}x)\frac{dV_0}{dt}.$$
By the average principle, I can switch the quantities that vary rapidly by theirs average values:
$$\frac{dE}{dt}= \langle\dot{x}(m\ddot{x}+2{\alpha}V_0\mathrm{sech}^2({\alpha}x)\tanh({\alpha}x))\rangle -\langle \mathrm{sech}^2({\alpha}x)\rangle\frac{dV_0}{dt}.$$
By the equations of motion, the first term on the RHS is zero, then:
$$\frac{dE}{dt}= -\langle \mathrm{sech}^2({\alpha}x)\rangle\frac{dV_0}{dt}$$

> Yeah... I'm  struggling to calculate this last average value. Did I do something wrong? any help will be very appreciated!